# XPath, how to delete Euro sign unnecessary characters?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, character, euro

How do i select the text in the span tag that excludes those unnecessary "&nbsp" characters? I need only the number (euro character at the end would be nice, but it's not a must). Note that the numbers change, they are not the same.

```
<span class="price">15.900&nbsp;€</span>
```

Comment: Is that XML or HTML?

Comment: text = text.Replace("&nbsp;","");

Comment: HTML, i'm practicing webscraping.

Comment: H.G. Sandhagen, is that Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use C# and XPath then assuming you write your XPath expression as a C# string you can use `"translate(//span[@class = 'price'], '\u00A0', '')"`.

Working sample (in Javascript) is

```js
console.log(document.evaluate("translate(//span[@class = 'price'], '\u00A0', '')", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).stringValue);
```

```html
<span class="price">15.900&nbsp;€</span>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate that /u00A0, ' ' part?

Comment: Well, see Unicode escape sequence in the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx#String%20Escape%20Sequences. And it is `\u00A0` and not `/u00A0`.

Comment: And in HTML the entity reference `nbsp;` is just the HTML way of writing the Unicode character U00A0 which Javascript or C# string literals allow you to escape as `\u00A0`.